# Best practice to save object in cache

Tags: json, caching, amazon-web-services, redis

I'm using Redis as a cache service (Key=>Value) @ AWS ElastiCache.

I want to save an object which contains nested objects inside the cache:

- Object1 - contains instance of Object2

I'm obviously serialising my objects - let's say to JSON for that matter - so my serialised object looks like this:

```
{
 "property1":"property1",
 "property2":"property2",
 "property2":"property3", 
 "object2":{ 
       object2
        }
}
```

I'm wondering what will be the best practice from the following options:

1. Store under my key the whole object1 as a full JSON.
2. Store object2 with its own key and in my object1 serialisation to put object2  key as a reference, and when pulling back from the cache, to pull object2 through its key as well.

My guts feels that option 1 is the best practice and the most efficient, but I have second thoughts storing big nested objects under on key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no generic optimal solution for your scenario. It depends on how you need to query your data.

If you always get the root object from your service or client, actually you're right storing the entire JSON in a string key.

In the other hand, if you need to also query associated objects, you'll need to both store each entire object graph in string keys, but you'll also need to store each associated object in a hash `parentobject:[id]` and the whole hash will store direct associations there where the key will be the associated object identifiers and the value the associated JSON-serialized object.

And depending on how you want to query both root and associated objects, you'll need to index them in sets, sorted sets and/or lists, or even other hashes.

As I said above, there's no definitive solution but you need to make a good case study and think how you're going to store your data in Redis carefully, because a bad data storage design can turn into an endless pain in your project.

Think about Redis like a data index. It's like if you would be implementing relational database indexes manually.

Comment: If you're taking the "root" approach, you can save RAM by storing a zipped JSON value or by using a more efficient protocol such as msgpack

Comment: @ItamarHaber Yeah, in my case, I'm "gzipping" JSON strings